# CheckBox Value not in True/False but in Text

Tags: vba, ms-office

Have a Code which aims to change to display a Text rather than a True/False Statement - And this with a Checkbox, I want to set the Value to something like

Checkbox is on -> Instead of True -> On!

Checkbox is on -> Instead of False-> Not On!

I tried to "hardcore it", but not sure how this would work...

```
Call UpdateBookmark("Bookmark1", Me.Checkbox1."On!")
```

Tried this...

```
If Me.Checkbox1.Value = True Then
Me.Checkbox1.Value = "On!"

End If
```

Comment: `Me.Checkbox1.Caption = "On!"` - ?? `Call UpdateBookmark("Bookmark1", Me.Checkbox1.Caption)` - ?? or maybe `= Iif(Me.Checkbox1.Value, "On!", "Not On!")` - ??

Comment: `If CheckBox1.Value Then CheckBox1.Caption = "On!" Else CheckBox1.Caption = "Not on!"`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```vb
Call UpdateBookmark("Bookmark1", IIf(Me!Checkbox1Value, "On!", "Not On!"))
```